# Multiple partial views. Id collision

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

I'm using DataTables in my project and I want to place two similar lists in one page. I've dicided to use the same partial view for both, but when I tried to apply DataTables functionality to them, I've got an Id's collision.

My partial view:

```
<table style=" margin:0" id="incidents">
...
</table
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#incidents').DataTable();
```

My parent view:

```
<h2>Important incidents</h2>
@Html.Partial("Incidents", Model.Where(m => m.Relevance == true)
<h2>Other incidents</h2>
@Html.Partial("Incidents", Model.Where(m => m.Relevance == false).Where(m=>m.Date>DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-6).AddDays(-5)))
```

Is it possible to do this without creating two similar partial views?

Comment: why don't you load two partial views in separate tables

Comment: @Exception do you mean creating two partial views with the only difference in the table Id?

Comment: You can give the tables different `id` attributes by passing a value from the main view to the partial using ViewDataDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the tables different `id` attributes by passing a value from the main view to the partial using `ViewDataDictionary`

Main view

```
<h2>Important incidents</h2>
@Html.Partial("Incidents", Model.Where(...), new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", "important" } })
<h2>Other incidents</h2>
@Html.Partial("Incidents", Model.Where(...), new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", "other" } })

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#important').DataTable();
  $('#other').DataTable();
```

Partial

```
<table id="@ViewData["id"]">
  ....
</table>
```